# XSL processing with Qt with included XML

Tags: xml, qt, xslt, qt4.8

I want to show a XSL styled XML file into a QWebView. Following lines are working fine:

```
QUrl xmlUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog_with_xsl.xml");
QUrl xslUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/cdcatalog.xsl");

QString html;
QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
query.setFocus(xmlUrl);
query.setQuery(xslUrl);
query.evaluateTo(&html);

this->m_webview->setHtml(html);
```

But in the XML file is already the same xsl file embedded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
```

Is there a way to show the XSL styled XML without parse the XML File?
The best case would be, if Qt would do this automatically.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; You'd like to show the result of the transformation without parsing the input XML document?

Comment: Yes, I want Qt by itself to tranform it.

Comment: Typically, libraries do not allow this kind of automatic transformation. The `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` instruction is mainly used by browsers. Why is explicitly transforming the input a problem for you?

Comment: Because I don't want to download the XML, parse the XML, get the Stylesheet path and check if it is a relative or an absolute path and so on =/